# Sylius themes not showing on channels

Tags: sylius

I have followed the steps to create themes according to Sylius doc.
After run php bin/console sylius:theme:assets:install, login to backend, but no theme showing under channel.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the reason. Some how the clear cache default on dev environment but actually I only have prod environment.

After cleared cache on prod:
php bin/console --env=prod --no-debug cache:clear

the theme showing up.

Also, since I cannot find how to setup dev env, I have cloned the prod db to `sylius_dev` and run:
http://[my ip]/app_dev.php

If you are not using 127.0.0.1, you need to add to:
\web\app_dev.php

Hope this help for someone new to Sylius and Symphony like me.